# How can i set layers name from map to combobox?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I'd like to list map layers from map into combobox. I tried to set itemsource of combobox to: `ItemsSource = "{Binding ElementName=Map, Path=Layers}`. It does not list the layer names. It just lists "Esri.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureLayer". How can I list layers with their names in my combobox?

Answer (score 2):

I found it :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmblayers"  ItemsSource ="{Binding ElementName=Map, Path=Layers}"    >

                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LayerInfo.Name}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

</ComboBox>
```